# Не получается сделать сохранение текста в unity через c# (пытаюсь сохранить через PlayerPrefs)

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Mane : MonoBehaviour{  

public GameObject ShowText;
public GameObject Info;

public InputField Food;
public InputField Medicaments;




public Text ShowFood;
public Text Foodtext;
public Text ShowMedicaments;
public Text Medicamentstext;


    public void Update()
    {
        ShowFood.text = Foodtext.text;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("save", ShowFood.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }


    public void Load()
    {
        ShowFood.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("save");

    } 





    public void OK()
    {
        Info.SetActive (false);
        ShowText.SetActive (true);

        ShowFood.text = Foodtext.text;
        ShowMedicaments.text = Medicamentstext.text + "₽";

    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        Info.SetActive (true);
        ShowText.SetActive (false);

        Medicamentstext.text = ShowMedicaments.text;
    }
```

Comment: что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Вы создали функции но не призывали их. Поэтому они и не работают. Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: И вообще не понятно зачем так много видов сохранения.

Comment: пожалуйста, объясните, как призывать функции? как их активировать? кроме как по нажатию в самом приложение? простите за такие заурядные вопросы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам исправленный, короткий и более понятный код.

```cs
void Start()
{
    Load();
}

//Это у вас будет одна единственная функция сохранения, добавить ещё не надо. Можете добавить эту функцию где угодно.
public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("save", ShowFood.text);
}

public void Load()
{
    ShowFood.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("save");
}
```

А потом несколько советов:

- Непонятно зачем вы добавили сохранение в `Update`. Сохранять каждые 0.02 сек это перебор.
- Не надо создать ещё одно сохранение только используйте функцию `Save` где надо сохранять, даже в функциях.
- Вместо
  `public Text ShowFood;
  public Text Foodtext;
  public Text ShowMedicaments;
  public Text Medicamentstext;`
  можете писать
  `public Text ShowFood, Foodtext, ShowMedicaments, Medicamentstext;`

Comment: спасибо за советы, я просто новичок в вопросах программирование и мне предстоит еще многое наверстать

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!! У МЕНЯ НАКОНЕЦ-ТО ВСЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ

Comment: @dreamboy, если ответ правильный, не забывайте его оценивать и помечать как "Правильный"